# SQL network error 26 win forms

Tags: sql, winforms, networking

I'm constantly getting this error when I try to **add** service based database to my new project (windows forms).

Same thing happens when I try to compile project which I have finished before (I haven't changed a single line of code)

The strangest thing of all is that I get same error when I try to run any of my programs using database.

Thx in advanced

IMG: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjgHm.jpg

Answer (score 0):

This is because your connection string is wrong.  One possibility is you specified one of the following parameters wrongly; server name, port number, username, password etc.

Also, this site rocks to check your syntax: http://www.connectionstrings.com/